# Can I cancel Ubuntu Update-Manager in progress?

Tags: ubuntu, synaptic-pkg-mgr

I am using Ubuntu 9.10 and am bothered by the sometimes pretty long update progress. Sometimes I wish to abort the update-manager, apt-get or synaptic because I need to go, but I think it might break anything. How can I do it safely, even if some cleaning up is required afterwards?

Comment: Nah, you can abort them.  You just have to run it again and it will restart the install.

Comment: if this is true, how would you do it? please post your answer as an answer, not as a comment..

Answer (score 3):

The package manager first downloads all packages and then installs them. As long as it's downloading you can interrupt it any time without any problems.

Interrupting after the installation started may sometimes break things and you should avoid this if possible.

Usually starting the update process again will continue fine, maybe asking you to run some command from the command line. But you better don't switch off your system before all the updates are completed.

Comment: +1 Although I didn't experienced it directly, it seems fair enough.